# Why does Vim force programming indentation when in "gitcommit" filetype?

Tags: indentation, filetype-git, version-control-systems

I found that when I am using Vim to compose git commit messages (which I have been doing for a very long time now) that there are occasionally some quirks.

For example today I wrote a commit message that began with the word "do".

This actually forces the second line to be indented for me. Likely because do is often a keyword that initiates a `do`...`while` loop.

How can I make modifications to syntax definitions to remove this behavior?

When I am in this situation, the `formatoptions` is set to `caq1njwtl`. However, I don't think that this is relevant because I don't really care about having my message auto-wrapped, I just want it to not apply any indentation.

Comment: I think the correct answer is almost certainly an autocommand based on the gitcommit filetype. I'll post it if I can come up with one myself.

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce your issue? I set the formatoptions to `caq1njwtl`, do `git commit`, and hit i (for insert mode), type `do` and hit enter ... Am I doing it right? ... I can't get the gitcommit filetype to apply auto-indent no matter what I do ... There isn't even an `indent/git*.vim` file on my system?

Comment: While you're typing a commit message, if you try typing `:set ft?` and hitting enter, what is the output?

Comment: It's `gitcommit`. I solved it. Posting answer now.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yeah, my `.vimrc` is 1703 lines and 52K in size at present. I'm not surprised at all that this isn't reproduced with vanilla vim.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I solved the problem, by adding to my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType gitcommit set nosmartindent | set formatoptions-=t
```

This removes the option that causes the lines to auto-wrap (which is another tweak I also made -- take out the last part including the `|` if you do not want to change this).

The take-away here is that `nosmartindent` is the trick to addressing any undesired auto indentation behaviors.

Comment: `smartindent` is something you only want to enable in C, and maybe a few languages with a syntax that's very similar... I think it's a leftover from before Vim had indent files for different languages.

Comment: Yeah maybe I will test with smartindent removed from my configuration and enabling it only for specific C-style filetypes (and javascript, etc). I already have an autocmd for Python that disables it as well, which was put in place for reasons quickly becoming obvious.

Comment: Even without filetype-specific indent scripts, `'cindent'` has replaced the functionality of `'smartindent'`.